# Time synchronization

Tags: real-time

I have a robot receiving images from a camera. Now, there is a denso device for **time synchronization** so that we get correct time stamping between of the camera frames. I am not sure what does that mean? Can you please explain this process?

Comment: what is a denso device? ... please add a link to the device datasheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confusing question for me because I don't understand why you're looking at the device if you're not sure what it does. Was this recommended to you? By whom? What did they say when you asked them why you would use one?

As [jsotola mentioned](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23666/time-synchronization#comment38316_23666), you haven't given us a datasheet or a clear use case, so I can't comment on specifics, but generally speaking I would expect it will do one of two things:

1. Give you a timestamp for when *exactly* the frames were captured, OR
2. Trigger the cameras to capture a frame at an exact timestamp.

In both cases, the point is synchronization between either the cameras or between each camera and the chassis.

If you're doing something like stereo vision, then you would want to know that differences between the left and right cameras are due to depth disparity and not due to object motion in the time between captures. This requires the scene to be stationary while the left and right images are captured. You can't control the scene, but you CAN control when the images are captured.

In a somewhat similar scenario, you may want to index your images to a particular position, for something like [structure from motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion), etc. This would mean indexing the image to the chassis position, which would require you to know when the image was taken.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The device name is Hercules Denso Device. It's used to timestamp each frame that comes from robot to laptop. I am not sure why we need it though.

Comment: @Avv - depends on how much you're affected by delays in processing times. Probably you don't need it, but it would depend on your use case, I suppose.

Comment: So timestamping is done by the laptop/robot after receiving a signal from the denso device please?

Comment: @Avv Not sure what exactly you're asking, but that sounds like a question for a Denso sales application engineer to answer. Sales application engineers are an awesome resource and I would highly encourage you to reach out to them directly - they can tell you what applications would benefit from the device, how they work, how you use the output, etc. Their job is to explain the technical specifics to you in a way that shows you how to use them, so you'll buy some and use them.